# вставить в форму повторяющиеся элементы из выпадающего списка html

Tags: html

Есть список с опциями. Вопрос: как сделать выпадающий список "form" html с этими опциями, чтобы выбранный элемент сразу записывался в поле ввода "form", при этом должна оставаться возможность продолжать дальнейший выбор опций, в том числе и повторного ввода одной и той же опции. То есть если список состоит из [1, 2, 3, 4], то можно было бы записать в поле ввода [1, 2, 1, 1] после чего нажать на кнопку "рассчитать". На сколько я понимаю, атрибут "multiple" в select не подходит, так как не позволяет дублировать опции.

Comment: одним html не обойтись. придется подключить javascript и с его помощью заполнять поле ввода по клику на список

Comment: забыл уточнить: приложение на flask

Comment: никакой разницы. на чем написана серверная часть, на клиенте придется использовать Javascript, чтобы реализовать требуемое поведение формы.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что нужно в имеющийся html-файл вставить код на javascript, реализующий требуемое поведение формы?

Comment: Да, все правильно, либо вставить в html-файл сам код, либо сделать ссылку на файл js из html-файла. Обычно это ссылки внутри `<head>` вида `<script async="" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Спасибо, пошел изучать javascript )

Comment: Там по идее форма несложная, я в ответе написал на всякий случай.

Answer (score 0):

Вот примерно такая должна быть форма по идее.

```html
<select name="options">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input id="selected_options" />
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  var target_input = document.getElementById('selected_options');
  var options = document.querySelector('[name="options"]');
  options.addEventListener('change', function() {
    target_input.value += (target_input.value) ? ', ' + options.value : options.value;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Обязательно ли указывать size? В моём случае он будет всегда разный

Comment: да нет, исправил код, чтобы отслеживать не клик, а изменение `select`

Comment: А код просто завернуть в <script></script> без атрибутов?

Comment: не понял, что вы имеете в виду под `без атрибутов`. А подключить код можно любым способ, в тос числе и да, хоть между `<script></script>`

Comment: почему-то не вставляет выбранные опции в <input>, я так понимаю js код связан с этой формой по id="selected_options"?

Comment: Вставил полностью Ваш код в свой html - не работает. Выпадающий список есть, а в input не вставляет при нажатии

Comment: Вставьте так, как сейчас. А вообще, конечно, лучше почитайте про javascript. Так вам сложно будет проект разрабатывать.

Comment: Да! Сейчас заработало, спасибо большое. Сам бы 3 дня разбирался. Сначала без этого не работало, правильно понимаю window.addEventListener('load', function(){